# Find the general equation formed by three points

Tags: vectors

I have to find the general equation defined by these 3 points:

What I have tried so far:

Unfortunately, I was told that my solution is wrong and I am not sure how else to solve/approach this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How do you mean '*general equation*' defined by 3 points? Do you perhaps mean the *equation of their* (affine) *plane*? Or perhaps the *area* of the triangle $ABC$?

Comment: Can you please check whether there is a typo? Over here, you mention the $z$-coordinate of point C to be $2$ but over the included picture it's $-2$.

Comment: @Berci I think it's the first one. I used rough translation, not English native.

Comment: @WingedBladesofGodric it's -2. C=[0,-2,-2].

Comment: There's also a sign error in the calculation of the value of your second determinant (the one with $j$)

Comment: @WingedBladesofGodric my calculation is the following: `2 * (-4) - (-4) * (-1)` = `-8 - 4` = `-12`.

Comment: Which part did I miss?

Comment: You have yourself written a negative sign prior to the determinant expansion; which is quite correct. Do you know why that happens? At any case, the stuff becomes $(- ( 2 * (-4) - (-4) * (-1) ) )$ $=$ $(-(-12))$ $=$ $12$.

Comment: Why have you deleted the bulk of your question?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write $$\vec{x}=\vec{OA}+s\vec{AB}+t\vec{AC}$$ where $s,t$ are real numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! But I'm not really sure how to use this. What is `OA` and where do I get the `s` and `t` from? I'd appreciate a more detailed explanation as I'm not very advanced.

Comment: See here http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/EqnsOfPlanes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we're after the equation of the *plane* $ABC$, you're on the right direction.

You already found a *normal vector* of that plane, though missed a sign, it should be $n=(-12,\ {\pmb +}12,\ -6)$, so the equation will indeed contain $-12x+12y-6y$ on one side, but the other side, which is going to be a constant, is still to be found. 
For that, simply put the coordinates of a point on the $ABC$ plane (say, either $A$, $B$ or $C$) into this expression, and that will give you the constant. 
[If they happen not to match for any choice of $A$, $B$ or $C$, that would mean you made a mistake in your previous calculations.]

So, now it's
$$-12x+12y-6y\ =\ -12\cdot{\bf1}+12\cdot{\bf1}-6\cdot{\bf2}\ =\ -12$$
or, equivalently,
$$2x-2y+z=2$$
You can verify that each of $A,B,C$ indeed satisfies it.

Comment: Normal vector ought be $(-12, 12, -6)$; assuming that I've not gone crazy.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I actually didn't calculate it, relied on the posted image of the attempted solution..

Comment: The part I don't understand is how to find the constant. Could you explain in a better way? With an example if possible (I don't understand all English terms). Thanks!

Comment: We're looking for an equation of the form $2x-2y+z=c$, and $A$ must satisfy it, so just put in its coordinates to find $c$. If the calculations are correct, you must get the same $c$ if you put $B$'s or $C$'s coordinates.

Comment: Ohh, that makes more sense, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Solve

$$\begin{cases}
1\cdot a+1\cdot b+2\cdot c+d=0,
\\3\cdot a+1\cdot b-2\cdot c+d=0,
\\0\cdot a-2\cdot b-2\cdot c+d=0.
\end{cases}$$

You can set one of the coefficients arbitrarily and solve for the others.